# Push Notification React Native Expo with Django RestFramework

Tags: python, django, react-native, notifications, expo

I am a newbie with notification using React Native Expo, and all Tutorials that I have searched so far is integrated with Firebase, But I am working on Django Rest Framework, I could not find any example, except on the Expo Documentation . I know all the mechanism, but I am struggling on the usage of Python Library :
https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-python

If anyone has an example on how to use it,
I'd be much appreciated.